# Is there any benefit to conda create --prefix over --name?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I have been using the Anaconda Python distribution for a long time now.  I have always used:

```
conda create -n bunnies python=2.7
```

or the like to create my environments within conda.  This works great but I recently was looking at a new [cheat sheet](https://conda.io/docs/_downloads/conda-cheatsheet.pdf) that Continuum put out that uses `-p` or `--prefix` to create environments.  For example:

```
conda create --prefix ~/py34 python=3.4
```

Other than the control over where the environment information is stored, is there any other reason why this is preferable than just `--name` (or `-n`) way to create my conda environments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anaconda is installed in the directory $CONDADIR, 
"conda create -n py34" will seek to create an environment at "$CONDADIR/envs/py34" . This is fine, if you own the directory and the directory is large enough for the contents of the complete environment.
Otherwise, you may find it better to use 
    "conda create --prefix $MyConda/envs/py34 python=3.4"
followed by the appropriate "activate" command.